# typescript How to define an ordered iterator type?

Tags: typescript

```js
interface TestIterator {
    0: boolean;
    1: any;
    2: "abc";
    length: 3;
    [Symbol.iterator]: typeof Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator];
}

// I want to build an iterator type that can be used for unpacking, which can still keep the correct type order after unpacking
const arr: TestIterator = [true, {}, "abc"]

// The following a1, a2, a3 cannot get the correct type
const [a1, a2, a3] = arr
```

I tried to look at the types constructed by the generator, and I was surprised to find that the types constructed by the generator could not keep the order of types either

```js
function *gen()
{
    yield "abc";
    yield true;
    yield 123;
}

const view_inference_type = gen(); // The generator gets the type： const view_inference_type: Generator<true | "abc" | 123, void, unknown>

const [g1, g2, g3] = view_inference_type; // All types of g1 g2 g3 are true | "abc" | 123 .This surprises me. Normally, we expect the unpackaged types to be sequential and accurate enough
```

The real problem I have is that I'm using the merging feature of the interface to extend Axios's AxiosResponse interface so that it can unpack, but my current approach doesn't get the right type, so the tuple approach deviates from the problem.

```js
declare module "axios"
{

    interface AxiosResponse {
        0: boolean;
        1: any;
        2: "async_try";
        length: 3;
        [Symbol.iterator]: Array[Symbol.iterator];

    }

}
```

Is there a way to order the types of iterators or generators, or to specify the order of types manually?

Comment: Seems like the number of elements your iterator returns is fixed, so how about using a list? `type TestList = [string, boolean, number]`

Answer (score 0):

for your scenario, I think the correct structure is tuple.
checkout the official doc.

`type TestTuple = [boolean, any,string];`

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types

Comment: This approach deviates from the problem, in fact I want to use the interface's merging capabilities to transform the interface types exposed by third-party libraries. For example, the axios library exposes the AxiosResponse type. I want to extend it so that it becomes an unpacked iterator with the correct type after unpacked.

Comment: The actual code I wrote is as follows：

Comment: ```typescript
declare module "axios"
{

    interface AxiosResponse {
        0: boolean;
        1: any;
        2: "async_try";
        length: 3;
        [Symbol.iterator]: Array[Symbol.iterator];

    }

}
```